# Undefined function - Ginkgo testing

Tags: go

I am trying to perform a set of tests against a function using the [Ginkgo](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) testing library. I have two scripts:

```
.
├── solve.go
└── solve_test.go
```

I am expecting the tests to run for the `Solve` function in `solve.go` as they are both within the same package.

When I execute the tests the console returns:

```
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
./solve_test.go:11:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:12:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:13:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:14:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:15:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:16:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:17:10: undefined: Solve
./solve_test.go:22:2: undefined: Solve
```

`solve.go`

```
package longest_vowel_chain

import "fmt"

func Solve(s string) int {
    for pos, char := range s {
        fmt.Println(char, pos)
    }

    return 0
}
```

`solve_test.go`

```
package longest_vowel_chain

import (
    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    "testing"
)

func TestSolve(t *testing.T) {
    It("Basic tests", func() {
        Expect(Solve("codewarriors")).To(Equal(2))
        Expect(Solve("suoidea")).To(Equal(3))
        Expect(Solve("ultrarevolutionariees")).To(Equal(3))
        Expect(Solve("strengthlessnesses")).To(Equal(1))
        Expect(Solve("cuboideonavicuare")).To(Equal(2))
        Expect(Solve("chrononhotonthuooaos")).To(Equal(5))
        Expect(Solve("iiihoovaeaaaoougjyaw")).To(Equal(8))
    })
}
```

I'm using Go 1.12.5 Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are your files placed in the $GOPATH?

Comment: Thanks @demas how do I check this?

Comment: `echo %GOPATH%` (in Windows command prompt) or `printenv | grep GOPATH` on Linux

Comment: Ok adding `Go Mod` fixed the issue. I think you're right that the `GOPATH` wasn't set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your source code into `$GOPATH` or use [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).